Design criteria of block ciphers in quantum setting
Some design criteria of block ciphers are already known for the resistance against known attacks like differential, linear , boomerang, etc. Does there already exist any study of design criteria of block ciphers against quantum attacks related to Simon's algorithm, Quantum Meet In The Middle attack, Quantum Impossible differential attack.

Simmons? I don't think Gus Simmons worked on this. Maybe Simon's algorithm?

Yes, you are right. This is a typo. Thank you.
